# how to draw from binomial with large-size changing probability without loops

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I want to draw only one number from binomial many times. Each draw corresponding to a specific probability (draw from Bernoulli with different probability). Please avoid loop.

I want to draw only one number from binomial many times. Each draw corresponding to a specific probability (draw from Bernoulli with different probability). Please avoid loop.

```
y<-c(1:10)
p<- dpois(y,2)  #probability vector

#error code below

rbinom(1,1,p) ###if p here is a vector, R will produce return one draw but I do not know the which probability the draw is from.
```

Comment: Why can't p be a vector? You should see what different vectors do in that command with different Ns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sapply(p,function(z){rbinom(1,1,z)})
```